# Can not get hiddenfield value

Tags: asp.net, knockout.js

I want to access the hidden field value in knockout.
Here is my html code

```
<td>
                        <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: status, disable: status, click: $root.UpdateStatus" />
                        <input id="hdnGoalId" type="hidden" data-bind="value: goalId" />
                    </td>
```

This is my javascript code

```
var WebmailViewModel = function() {

 self.UpdateNote = function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'SinglePageApp.aspx/UpdateNote',
        data: "{goalId: '" + self.goalId + "'}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (result) {
            alert(result.d);
        }
    });
};
};ko.applyBindings(new WebmailViewModel());
```

In UpdateNote i want to pass the selected goalId.
Please give me some advice.

Comment: You need to acces the hidden field bij doing :  $('#hdnGoalId input[type=hidden]').val();

Comment: i have applied this.But its showing undefined value.

Comment: I made a type at the id of the hiddeninput..>.<

Comment: @JonathanRomer your method does not fit the pattern of knockout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your response.I got the solution by updating like this

```
self.UpdateNote = function (tblUsers) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'SinglePageApp.aspx/UpdateNote',
        data: "{goalId: " + tblUsers.goalId + "}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (result) {
            alert(result.d);
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(textStatus);
            alert(errorThrown);
        }
    });
};
```

where tblUsers is the json object.

Answer (score 2):

I'm seeing two possible problems

1. *goalId* must be defined as observable, as you are binding to it in your view with `data-bind="value: goalId"`.
2. to get the value of *goalId* you must invoke it as a function (as it is an observable).

See the updated view model:

```
var WebmailViewModel = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.goalId = ko.observable(10); // where 10 is whatever value goalId should be
    self.UpdateNote = function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'SinglePageApp.aspx/UpdateNote',
            data: "{goalId: '" + self.goalId() + "'}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function(result) {
                alert(result.d);
            }
        });
    };
};
```

Comment: @akeeseth it's showing undefined because you're binding the value to an observable, but not setting the value anywhere. You'll want to do something like this: `self.goalId = ko.observable(10)` where `10` is whatever value goalId should have.